# Snowflake UDF returns "Unknown user-defined function" For Existing UDF

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF that I can call within my snowflakecomputing.com console.

```
SELECT DECODE_UTF8('some string')
```

Works great, until I try to call it programmatically from a Python script. I receive this...

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 002141 (42601):
or:
Unknown user-defined function CS_QA.CS_ANALYTICS.DECODE_UTF8
```

I am even fully qualifying it (i.e., db.schema.function)

Can anyone suggest a fix? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the user(and role assigned) used to connect from Python does not have access to that UDF. This hypothesis could be validated by using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FUNCTIONS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/functions.html):

> The view only displays objects for which the current role for the session has been granted access privileges.

```
SELECT *
FROM CS_QA.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FUNCTIONS;
```

---

Another possibility is that part of the fully-qualified name is case-sensitive and requires wrapping with `"`

```
SELECT "CS_QA"."CS_ANALYTICS".DECODE_UTF8('some string');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, You might have to first switch to database where the function has defined.

USE DATBASE USER_DEF;
SELECT DECODE_UTF8('some string')

That should work.